# excel vba compile error sub or function not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a simple for loop but I get en error:

> compile error: sub or function not defined

I made a module in vba:

```
Option Explicit

Sub 100group()

Dim i As Integer, E As Integer
  E = 101
  For i = 2 To 37317
    If (cell(i, 1) < E) Then cell(i, 3) = E Else E = E + 100
    End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

- `cell(i, 1)` should be `Cells(i, 1)`
- Also, sub/function.variable names cannot start with a number.
- Also also, Your `If` statement syntax is well out.
- Finally you will hit a further error because `i` is declared as an `Integer` which can only hold a value of up to 32,768. So you need:

  ```
  Dim i As Long
  ```

As a `Long` data type can hold a value of up to 2,147,483,647

---

To summarise, you should be using:

```
Option Explicit

Sub group100()

Dim i As Long, E As Long
  E = 101
  For i = 2 To 37317
      If (Cells(i, 1) < E) Then
          Cells(i, 3) = E 
      Else 
          E = E + 100
      End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Happy to help, please mark as the answer if it solved your issue.